# Errors for count() via Dev Console (No response from the server) and Workbench (future_get-9-1588268637)

Tags: apex, soql, query, workbench, query-editor

Need to test out different grouping strategies for a matching process I'm building. Problem is there are too many records to query the data for a count(). In dev console I get a 'communication failure: No response from the server' message. And in workbench I get the future_get-9-1588268637 error.

QUERY FOR BATCH

```
SELECT count() 
FROM data__c 
WHERE date__c >= 2020-02-01 AND 
      date__c <= 2020-02-28 AND
      data2__r.program__c LIKE '%test%'
```

I know there are people who have to work with millions of records.. how come it's so difficult to work with a few hundred thousand? Any suggestions

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using `data.prgoram__c` instead of `prgoram__c`? Or is the field name actually `Program__c`?

Comment: The issue here is likely you are using a none selective query. The fields you are using may not be indexed and that like operator is very expensive while querying.

Comment: @AdrianLarson not the actual field names ^ just sample.

Comment: Try to set the `prgoram__c` (or whichever field it is) as ExternalId to force Salesforce to index it. (I'm afraid that to index date fields you will have to get in contact with support)

Comment: @SergioAlcocer I'll give that a shot. Does setting as ExternalId create any conflict with processes that reference its Salesforce Id?

Comment: @manjit5190 Thank you. The fields are not indexed. I'm going to try to use Sergios suggestion about forcing an index on the program field.