# SOQL vs Reports: Why is server losing connection when I run equivalent SOQL from Query Editor?

Tags: apex, soql, workbench, externalid, indexing

I have a Batch process which accepts 300,000 or so records from its query. When I run the query as a standalone in Query Editor or in Workbench, I get errors (discussed in last post [Errors for count() via Dev Console (No response from the server) and Workbench (future_get-9-1588268637)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/304483/errors-for-count-via-dev-console-no-response-from-the-server-and-workbench)).

I thought this was a problem with table size and a lack of indexes, as suggested in above ref post. But if that were so, why does it work with a standard report - which displays the 350,000 records in a matter of seconds?

The query generalizes to this:

```
SELECT count() 
FROM data__c 
WHERE date__c >= 2020-02-01 AND 
      date__c <= 2020-02-28 AND
      data2__r.program__c LIKE '%test%' AND 
      id IN :ids
```

All of the fields in the query are either indexed or an external Id, so I don't believe it is running as a non-indexed query. Overall it just doesn't make any sense to me. You would think as a developer, the stronger tools are the ones in the dev console, not on the client side. I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Taylor

Comment: Indexed fields have their limits as well. I would suggest removing the criteria one by one see the query cost. It can be the case where in reports the optimizer uses a Where date__c month =2 and date__c Year =2020 which would be a more efficient query than yours or maybe reports is using SOSL for `test` and then a SOQL for others.

Comment: Have you used the developer console query plan to see the cost (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/database_basics_dotnet/writing_efficient_queries)? It doesn't look like a costly query. Another option would be try a data chunking technique (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/pk-chunking-techniques-massive-orgs.html) or to request customer support a skinny table (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_skinny_tables.htm)